# Findbugs [Malicious code vulnerability | EI_EXPOSE_REP2] not thrown on self written classes

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

we have implemented spotbugs into our applications yesterday. Most of our bugs were `[Malicious code vulnerability | EI_EXPOSE_REP2]...may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into...`.

We understand this, but what we don't understand is, that these bugs were only thrown on Date classes. We have selfwritten classes which are held by other classes and this bug was not thrown there.

Why does it handle Date differently than selfwritten classes? The other classes are not immutable either. We mainly use lombok for getters, setters and builders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
class MyClass {

   private Date billDate;

   public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
      this.billDate = billDate;
   }

}
```

The solution is `this.billDate = new Date(billDate.getTime());`

```
class MyClass {

   private Date billDate;

   public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
      this.billDate = new Date(billDate.getTime());
   }

}
```